# Setting up basic Spring AOP configuration

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm learning Spring's AOP, following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop) tutorial, but somehow I cannot make it work. The only modification I made, I hope, is to make it work with a cotroller.

directory structure

```
-/java
    -/com.example.spring_aop
        -/aspects
            -LoggingAspect.java
        -/controllers
            -AddController.java
        -SpringAopApplication.java
-/resources
    -beans.xml
```

AddController.java

```
@RestController
public class AddController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/{a}+{b}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map add(@PathVariable("a") int a, @PathVariable("b") int b) {
        int result = a+b;
        return Collections.singletonMap("result", result);
    }
}
```

LoggingAspect.java

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Before("execution( * com.example.spring_aop.controllers..*.*(..) )")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.info(" ###### before executing method: {} of class: {}",
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution( * com.example.spring_aop.controllers..*.*(..) )",
            returning = "result")
    public void after(Object result) {
        logger.info(" ###### method returned: {}", result);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
Spring Web auto-generated (Spring Initializr) pom with one added dependency:

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the annotations equivalent you tried?

Comment: I've edited my post, but just for you (for me it's solved)

Comment: Great.  Your question on XML vs Annotations is a bit too big to answer here, I suggest reading up on the pros and cons :-).  You'll see from your example that it is more concise to use annotations, but there are a few reasons you might prefer to use XML.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I think the same way...

Comment: And the official answer is "it depends"
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-annotation-config

Comment: Please be advised to (a) not ask questions asking for opinionated answers because they are considered off-topic on SO and (b) create a real **answer** instead of posting the answer as part of the question. It is perfectly legal to answer your own question and then later even accept your own answer in order to close the question. BTW, you are do not answer just to one person here. You asked a community for help and post the answer for same community's benefit. It is not a personal favour but a matter of general courtesy, after maybe 50 or more people used their time to read your question. 

Comment: Thanks very much for clarifying how SO works, still learning :) I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by choosing annotation-based configuration over xml. The AspectJ annotations present in my question are actually sufficient, so I just deleted the `beans.xml` config and it works as expected.